# JavaScript Regex in frontend not matching the Java Pattern in backend

Tags: javascript, java, regex

I am trying to test that a string is alphanumeric, can only contain `_` and `-`, and does not contain any double hyphens.  So, I tested my regex phrase in the UI using the following format:

```
/^(?!.*--)[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$/.test("myString"); //true
/^(?!.*--)[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$/.test("my--String"); //false
```

However, when I try to implement this into my java back-end, it is failing the check.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?!.*--)[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+");
```

Is the format for the pattern object incorrect?

Comment: Is it Java or JavaScript?

Comment: I was testing the pattern originally in my console, so JavaScript, and the pattern I created was correctly checking for the required syntax.  I tried to copy the pattern into my java code to implement a Pattern object, but it fails the check in my java code.

Comment: Could it be just because you did not add the boundary matchers in your code? Should be like this : `Pattern.compile("^(?!.*--)[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$");`

Comment: @SWLim hmm, could be.  I thought java doesn't need the perl starting and anchor tags for regex?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular expression to match line that doesn't contain a word?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word)

Comment: I don't think it's just for Perl. Here's the doc for Java's boundary matchers
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/bounds.html

Btw, for alpha numeric, you could just do [\w] as well, instead of [a-zA-Z0-9]

Comment: @SWLim Thanks, I will try that now.  And TemporalWolf, The pattern I have works in Perl, I am just having difficulty applying the pattern to my Java Pattern object.

Comment: With the given pattern `pattern.matcher("myString").matches()` will be evaluated to `true` and `pattern.matcher("my--String").matches()` will be evaluated to `false`. Your pattern is correct, but maybe the following code is incorrect.